# How to show Ajax response as modal popup

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, ajax

I have a link on clicking it is sending `ajax` request and getting response successfully which is html file and I am appending to a `div`, but I need to show that `div` as `modal popup` and I tried something below.

in `html` file

```
<a th:if="${ratingSummary}" href="#"  class="small dark account review_ratings_login">Login to write a review</a> 

<div id="login_for_review" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reviewLoginModal"></div>
```

in `js` file

```
$(document).on('click', '.review_ratings_login', function () {
        var $data = $('#review_product_id span').text();
         var url = '/mycompany/login/'+$data;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function (output) {
            $('#login_for_review').html(output).modal('show');// I tried to show this response as modal popup
            },
            error: function(output){
            alert("fail");
            }
        });
    });
```

`output` file

```
<div  class="centerForm modal fade" role="dialog" style="margin-left: 35%;" id="reviewLoginModal">

      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" >
       <div class="modal-content">
          // here I have login form
    </div>
  </div>
```

but I am not getting this `html output` as `modal pup` instead I am getting `black screen` can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating modal and by removing `data-toggle` and `data-target` and just appending  response to that  `modal div`

**Code For modal div**

```
<div id="login_for_review" class="modal hide"  role="dialog">

</div>
```

**Code For hyperlink**

```
 <a th:if="${ratingSummary}" href="#"  class="small dark account review_ratings_login">Login to write a review</a>
```

**Code For ajax call**

```
$(document).on('click', '.review_ratings_login', function () {
        var $data = $('#review_product_id span').text();
         var url = '/mycompany/login/'+$data;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function (output) {
            $('#login_for_review').html(output).modal('show');//now its working
            },
            error: function(output){
            alert("fail");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

In Bootsrap modal popup,  You can use plain way to show modal which don't need pre-defined modal div container . see at [modal](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/)

For E.g

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "url",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "html",
                data:{id:params},
                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    if(data==""){
                        window.location.href="/";
                    }
                    else{
                        BootstrapDialog.show({
                            title: "Modal Tital",
                            message: function(dialogRef){
                                $mydata = $($.parseHTML(data));
                                return $mydata;
                            },
                            onshow: function(dialog){

                        // and css change if need, eg. 
                         dialog.$modalHeader.css("float","none");

                            },
                            onshown:function(dialog)
                            {
                               // event after shown

                            },
                            onhide:function(dailog)
                            {
                               // event on hide
                            }
                        });
                    }

                },
                statusCode: {
                    401: function () {
                        alert("Your session has been expired");

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Aghere thanks for you reply, but I solved my problem in different approach please check my answer

Comment: This seems like the best and most modern solution for 2016, strange it I am the first to upvote it