# What's this kind of browser called?

Tags: browser, cross-browser

I just want create a Popup like this, but I can't find correct name of this to googling it
[Image added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQpOr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you creating it in?

I know Ajax has a modalpopup control in the Ajax Toolkit

https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit/?utm_source=Web&utm_medium=SiteShortcut&utm_campaign=AjaxControlToolkit&utm_content=AjaxControlToolkit_Web_SiteShortcut

Basically you make a form and then display it as a modalpopup

Comment: Thanks for anwser my question. I Just want to know how to call a dialog browser like image I added.

Comment: You can check this thread, it may help clarify more (see second answer for ajax solution):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007345/how-to-show-ajax-response-as-modal-popup